# How do I add up all the numbers 1:1000 in a for loop?

Tags: r

I'm teaching myself R and I'm using a worksheet and have gotten to learning for loops:

I understand that basically it is written like this:

```
for (value in vector) {
   statements
}
```

I've tried different methods and looked online but it just confuses me. Can anyone help?

Q60. add up all the numbers from 1 to 1000 using the `sum()` function

```
sum(1:1000)
```

okay easy enough...

Q61. add up all the numbers from 1 to 1000 using a `for` loop???

```
for(i in c(1:1000)){print(sum(i))}
```

doesn't work.

I'm trying to get `500500`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use a for loop, you can do this:

```
> sum <- 0
> for(i in 1:1000) {
+   sum <- sum+i
+ }
> sum
[1] 500500
```

Comment: Thank you, I realise the question is a bit weird but I guess it's for teaching. :)

Comment: no problems! Yes - agreed, as you can see from the other response there are MANY ways of writing the code to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid a for loop and use `cumsum()`:

```
max(cumsum(1:1000))

[1] 500500
```

Or you can use `Reduce()` with `accumulate = FALSE` (as suggested by @Bulat):

```
Reduce("+", 1:1000, accumulate = FALSE)
```

Comment: Probably more generalized way would be using `Reduce` function

Comment: Thanks, I'll note them down for use later. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Reduce seems like a handy function to have around :)

Comment: Any reason for downvote? Is there a problem with the code/post?

Comment: No problems on my end - you've both been very helpful. Thank you again :)